# Doctrine: Можно ли сделать сортировку в коллекции в сущности?

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

У меня есть сущность Компании и связанная с ней сущность Альбом (1:m). То есть есть компания и в ней коллекция альбомов с фотографиями.
Допустим у меня также есть кучка просто левых фотографий и я хочу при выводе на страницу сделать из них дефолтный альбом. Я руками создаю этот альбом, добавляю в него эти фотографии, альбом добавляю в коллекцию в компанию. Все замечательно, но этот альбом, естественно, в конце. Я хочу, чтобы он был первым. Можно ли как-то сделать сортировку?

Пока что единственное решение, это выбрать все альбомы из коллекции в переменную, удалить их из коллекции, добавить в коллекцию дефолтный альбом, добавить все остальные.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно. Это делается достаточно просто через комментарии:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Company
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Album")
     * @OrderBy({"sortOrder" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $albums;
}
```

Вам необходимо добавить поле для сортировки, потому что если вы будете сортировать альбомы по дате добавления, то вскоре еще один добавленный альбом в компанию станет "дефолтным".

Comment: Я добавляю альбом через `new CompanyAlbum()` в уже выбранную коллецию

Comment: `$company->albums->setAlbums(array_merge($myAlbum, $company->getAlbums()->toArray()))`

Comment: Это было бы круто, но так как `$company->albums` это `ArrayCollection`, `doctrine:generate:entities` создает только: 
`addAlbum()`
`removeAlbum()` и
`getAlbums()`

Comment: А что вам мешает добавить метод `setAlbums`?

Comment: А правильно ли что-то такое самостоятельно добавлять в Entity? Хотя действительно, почему бы и нет...

Comment: Не только правильно, но и во многих случаях необходимо. Доктрина требует только геттеры и сеттеры для свойств, всё остальное вы должны дописать сами для того, чтобы не выносить логику модели в контроллеры.